# Zimbra unable to email from mobile after upgrade to 8.0.3

Tags: email, mobile, zimbra, emailrelay

We recently upgraded our Zimbra FOSS email server to version 8.0.3, and since that upgrade all cell phones (Android and iPhone) give the error 'The recipient "email@domain.com" was rejected by the server because it does not allow relaying.'

I can not find anything that looks to have changed. Does anyone know if this is a known issue with version 8.0.3?

Thanks for any help with this issue...  I'm not having any luck fixing it, or even finding anything that actually pertains to it...

*Edit*

```
As an update:  I found the following information in my Zimbra.log...

Mar 26 16:58:21 server postfix/smtpd[22783]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from 29.sub-174-237-227.myvzw.com[174.237.227.29]: 554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [174.237.227.29] blocked using zen.spamhaus.org; http://www.spamhaus.org/query/bl?ip=174.237.227.29; from=<me@server.net> to=<me@server.net> proto=ESMTP helo=<[10.246.232.147]>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching the above edit, we found that the problem was (apparently) related to SpamHaus.org blocking the relaying of emails through the cell providers into Zimbra.  I turned off SpamHaus, and everything is working fine now...

Hope that helps if anyone else has this  issue...